# Como puedo "mapear" los índices de los caracteres de una palabra con PHP?

Tags: php, array, indices

Les comento estoy intentando aprender a trabajar con arrays y he optado por unos ejercicios que nunca he podido resolver, acá va uno.

Mapear los índices de las letras de una palabra
- Letras serán las claves
- Las posiciones serán los valores
- cereza > {c:[0],e:[1,3],r:[2],z:[4],a:[5]}

Tengo esto:

```
$string = "Cereza";
$datos = count_chars($string, 1);
foreach ($datos as $key => $value)
{
    $key = chr($key);
    echo "Letra $key, se repite $value veces<br>";
    // $x = array_combine($key, $value);
} 
Letra C, se repite 1 veces
Letra a, se repite 1 veces
Letra e, se repite 2 veces
Letra r, se repite 1 veces
Letra z, se repite 1 veces
```

Pero cuando quiero "combinar" mis keys (osea mis letras) con su posición es que no logro hacerlo. Alguna idea??

Muchas gracias chicos... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
<?php

$string = "Cereza";
$datos = count_chars($string, 1);
foreach($datos as $key => $value){
    $key=chr($key);
    $r[$key] = [];
    for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++){
        if($i==0) $r[$key][]=strpos($string,$key,0);
        else $r[$key][]=strpos($string,$key,$r[$key][$i-1]+1);
    }
} 

echo json_encode($r);
```

Y obtendrás:

```
{"C":[0],"a":[5],"e":[1,3],"r":[2],"z":[4]}
```

Comment: En efecto, es así, pero no capto la lógica del for. Es ahí donde me pierdo :-(

Comment: El for es para buscar N veces la letra en la palabra

Answer (score 1):

Con una estructura adecuada este problema se puede resolver mucho más fácil, por ejemplo, un array asociativo.

```php
<?php
$string = "Cereza";
$res = array();
foreach(mb_str_split($string) as $char) {
    $res[$char] = ($res[$char] ?? 0) + 1;
} 
// ###
print_r($res);
```

La salida será:

```
[C] => 1
[e] => 2
[r] => 1
[z] => 1
[a] => 1
```

[mb_str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-str-split) | [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (PHP 7+)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la función [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) para iterar por cada caracter y de ahí contar el número de veces que aparecen, y a su vez crear un array cuyos indices sean la letra y el valor sea el número de veces que aparecen.

Luego harías otro bucle para imprimir la información de cada letra. Con [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count) contaría el número de elementos en un array (las veces que aparece cada letra) y con [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode) convertirías el array en una cadena con las posiciones.

Ejemplo:

```php
$array = array();
$string = 'Cereza';
$datos = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach($datos as $posicion => $letra) {
    $array[$letra][] = $posicion;
}

// Para saber cuantas veces aparece cada letra:
foreach($array as $letra => $cantidad) {
    echo "La letra $letra aparece " . count($cantidad) . ' veces en las siguientes posiciones: ' . implode(', ', $cantidad) . '<br>';
}
```

Esto daría como resultado:

```
La letra C aparece 1 veces en las siguientes posiciones: 0
La letra e aparece 2 veces en las siguientes posiciones: 1, 3
La letra r aparece 1 veces en las siguientes posiciones: 2
La letra z aparece 1 veces en las siguientes posiciones: 4
La letra a aparece 1 veces en las siguientes posiciones: 5
```